# how to cut out the photo and display on web in ruby script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

the photo display sript is below:

```
    <% if user.image %>
      <%= image_tag user.image.url('100x20') %>
    <% end %>
```

How can I only showing the right side of the photo by 20 x 20 on the web. it mean cut off the 80% on the left show only 20% of the whole picture.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) on the server-side. You'll need to

```
> gem install rmagick
```

Or use whatever package manager you have. Once it's installed you should be able
to run the following:

```
require 'RMagick'

def cropImage(input_filename)
    original = Magick::ImageList.new(filename)
    # NorthEast says take from the top, right, corner. Start
    # at 20,20 and make the final image 20x20.
    crop = original.crop(NorthEast, 20,20,20,20)
    output_filename = "cropped-foo.jpg"
    crop.write(output_filename)
    return  output_filename
end
```

This will show only the top-right corner of an image.

If you want to crop you'll need to get the linked-to image, however you'd like. Perhaps using Net::HTTP, (or from your DB, it's unclear to me from your post)

```
Net::HTTP.start("EXAMPLE.COM") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/path/to/X.jpg")
  open("orig.jpg", "wb") do |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  end

   cropped_filename = cropImage("orig.jpg")
  #put the resulting file in some location where 
  #you can get to it and add that link to your 
  #template. 
end
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that, could you give more details how can I use RMagick on the server side please?

Comment: Are [CSS Masks](http://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) an option? Would showing a portion of an image at display time instead of cropping the image on the server offer any advantages?